# How do I NOT animate a list view in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, template10

This applies to UWP, how can I disable animation of list view items? I have a method that runs every few seconds, and the fly-in animation effect makes it visually displeasing. I want to disable the effect. Not much code to share, but here's my ListView:

```
<ListView RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" />
```

Comment: nothing to do with T10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to disable the transitions:

```
<ListView Transitions="{x:Null}"
          ItemContainerTransitions="{x:Null}">
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to prevent the list from jumping back to the top when it refreshes? In other words, can I preserve my scroll position?

Comment: Not sure how. Maybe create a new question and others can help.

Comment: The `Transitions` property doesn't seem to be available in code...?

Comment: @jbyrd, could you post a question with your code? Because it's definitely available in code for me.

Comment: @Laith - in a page, if I just create a ListView like `var lv = new ListView();` and then start typing `lv.Transi...`, nothing comes up in Intellisense - see https://snag.gy/lE8haS.jpg

Comment: @jbyrd, if you type out `lv.Transitions = null;`, does your project compile? If so, then you have an issue with your Visual Studio setup. If it doesn't compile, make sure you haven't created another class in your project called `ListView`. If so, try using the full namespace like this `var lv = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView();`

Comment: @Laith - oh I just realized the disconnect - I was talking about the Xamarin.Forms ListView. But you're talking about the UWP ListView - so I would need to set it in the UWP custom renderer. Got it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the scroll position, try this:

```
this.ListView.ScrollIntoView(ListView.SelectedItem);
```